# Downloading JSON into Table View in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, swift3

i want to show my data in tableview, i have a json data and i have watched this [tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpPXG.png). It's working but my json data doesn't have array key "actor". 
this is example's json data.

```
{
  "actors": [
    {
      "name": "Brad Pitt",
      "description": "William Bradley 'Brad' Pitt is an American actor and film producer. He has received a Golden Globe Award, a Screen Actors Guild Award, and three Academy Award nominations in acting categories",
      "dob": "December 18, 1963",
      "country": "United States",
      "height": "1.80 m",
      "spouse": "Jennifer Aniston",
      "children": "Shiloh Nouvel Jolie-Pitt, Maddox Chivan Jolie-Pitt",
      "image": "http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/brad.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tom Cruise",
      "description": "Tom Cruise, is an American film actor and producer. He has been nominated for three Academy Awards and has won three Golden Globe Awards. He started his career at age 19 in the 1981 film Endless Love.",
      "dob": "July 3, 1962",
      "country": "United States",
      "height": "1.70 m",
      "spouse": "Katie Holmes",
      "children": "Suri Cruise, Isabella Jane Cruise, Connor Cruise",
      "image": "http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/cruise.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

it's my json data.

```
[
      {
        "ID": 1,
        "name": "Amy"
      {
        "ID": 2,
        "name": "John"
      }
    ]
```

and it's my code;

```
func downloadJsonWithURL() {

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as? URL)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
            print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "actors"))

            if let studentArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "actors") as? NSArray {
                for student in studentArray{
                    if let studentDict = student as? NSDictionary {

                        if let name = studentDict.value(forKey: "ID") {
                            self.noArray.append(name as! String)
                        }
                        if let name = studentDict.value(forKey: "name") {
                            self.adiArray.append(name as! String)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

i have problem here;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpPXG.png)

and it will be a problem :/

```
        // my json data doesnt have "actors" ?????
        print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "actors"))
        if let studentArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "actors") as? NSArray {
            for student in studentArray{
                if let studentDict = student as? NSDictionary {
```

Comment: Don't force unwrap`!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've fixed problem.. i chanced jsonObj's line and closed actor's line

this;

```
if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSArray {}
```

and this

```
if let actorArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "actors") as? NSArray {
                    for student in jsonObj!{
                        if let studentDict = student as? NSDictionary {
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: There is nothing like actors in your JSON then how you are working with it, In your question you have told that actors is with tutorial JSON, this doesn't make any sense. Also in Swift you need to use native Array and dictionary just like my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41853675/6433023)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON response is of `Array` type not the `Dictionary`. In Swift use native Array instead of `NSArray`. So you need type cast the `jsonObject` result to `[[String:Any]]`.

```
if let array = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? [[String:Any]] {
    //Now loop through the array.
    for item in array {
        if let id = item["ID"] as? Int {
            self.noArray.append("\(id)")
        }
        if let name = item["name"] as? String {
           self.adiArray.append(name)
        }
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

**Note:** Instead of using multiple array you need to use single array of custom object or dictionary, So batter if you create one custom class and made array of it or use array of dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I recoment to use SwiftyJSON: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON. Easy instal with cocoapods: pod 'SwiftyJSON'

```
import SwiftyJSON

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "asd")!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

            guard error == nil else {

                print("there is an error \(error)")
                return
            }

            guard data != nil else {

                print("there is no data")
                return
            }

            let json = JSON(data: data)

            for actor in json["actors"].array {

                self.noArray.append(actor["ID"].int)
                self.adiArray.append(actor["name"].string)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }).resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first json have root element is Dictionary so your code is working for first json format. But the second json that you want to parse having the root elemt is array and you are trying to assign the array into dictionary that's why you are gettin error So just Replace your code with ..

```
if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:[]) as? NSArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
as! NSDictionary
```

To

```
as! [String : Any]
```